# “I woke up to my mom’s call.” vs “I woke up to a call from my mom.” Which is correct and why?

Tags: expressions

“I woke up to my mom’s call.” vs “I woke up to a call from my mom.” Which is correct and why?

I want to know which sentence is correct. Could you explain why in simple terms?

Comment: Why do you think that only one is correct?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Some people say that the former sounds unnatural.

Comment: Sounds unnatural why?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I don't know why, and my native English-speaking friend can't explain it because he hasn't studied English grammar. I want someone who can didactically explain why.

Comment: Think about this: He woke up to the bird's call. It's not that you can't say "mom's call" here but it sounds somewhat awkward. If you wrote: He woke to the sound of his mother's voice. That sounds good. This is not about grammar. It is about style of speaking.

Comment: Thanks~ It is about the style of speaking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not clear what, exactly you are asking about. Both sentences, however, are correct.

We talk about waking up to (something) when we wake up to find that something is happening. Sometimes, but not always, that can be the cause of our awakening. That (something) is usually expressed as a phrase using a noun - the sunlight coming through my window, a knock on the door, the realisation that today is my wedding day, the barking of my dog, the sound of the rain on the roof.

It is equally natural to talk about 'my mom's call' and 'a call from my mom'. The answer is 'yes'. they both mean the same thing. A 'call from your mom' might be a telephone call, or a vocal call, e.g. 'Cdleace, your breakfast is ready', or 'Cdleace, you're going to be late for school!'.

Answer (score 1):

**STYLE**

“I woke up **to the sound o**f my mother's voice."

"I woke up **to the sound of my telephone ringing".**

Generally, we say we **wake up to the sound of something**.

You can't wake up "to a call" when call means a telephone call.

- I woke up **when** my mother called me.
- I woke up **when** the phone rang.
- I **was woken up** by my mother's call.
- I **woke up to the sound of music** playing on the radio.
- **My mother's call woke me**. [the most natural way to say this]

Comment: But Michael Harvey told me that "A 'call from your mom' might be a telephone call.". Is he wrong?

Comment: @cdleace No, he's right.

Comment: I partly based my assertion that one can (these days) 'wake up to' a call from (e.g.) 'my mom' based on the notion that one can be awakened by a mobile phone ringing, and immediately see on the screen something like 'Mom', unlike in my youth where I would have had to pick up the phone to see who was calling. Do you think I should edit my answer?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Michael, I just don't much like "I woke up to a call" where call is a phone call. It just does not sound good. I woke up to music playing. Because really, one is woken or awoken BY a call.